# ViewModel is null on second jQuery Ajax post

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a page with a form per "Order".  Each "Order" has multiple "items".  Also, each form has an anchor tag "Mark as Shipped" that does a jQuery Ajax post.  This post will mark "Order" as shipped and return the orderID to the view.  On success of post I remove the form associated to the "Order" that was just marked shipped.  This is all working great.  Here is where the problems start.  When I click "Mark as Shipped" for the second "Order" in the list, the ViewModel is passed to the controller as null.  I do notice that the orderID is still being picked up by my js code on click of the anchor tag.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!  I'm pulling my hair out here.

Here is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(".MarkAsShipped").click(function () {
        var valid = true;
        var orderNumber = $(this).attr("data-id");
        var formID = "#" + orderNumber;

        if (valid) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/NeedsShipped/MarkAsShipped",
                type: "POST",
                data: $(formID).serialize(),
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    // remove the form for this order
                    $(formID).remove();                        
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Each form has a list of items in it.  Here is the part of my view that creates the forms.

```
 if (@Model.Count() > 1)
 {
 for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
 {
     using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = @Model[i].OrderID, name = @Model[i].OrderID }))
     {             
  <br />
  <div class="roundedDivVendor">          
      <div id="contactInfo" style="float:left; padding-left:5px; border-right:thin solid black; width:300px;">
          <span style="font-weight:bold;">Order Number: </span>
          @Model[i].OrderID<br />
          <span style="font-weight:bold;">Ship To:</span><br />
          @Model[i].FirstName.ToString()<span> </span>@Model[i].LastName.ToString()            

          <br />
          @Model[i].Address1
          @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].OrderID)
         <br /><br />
      </div>
      <div id="itemsToShip" style="padding-left:20px;">
        <span style="font-weight:bold; padding-left:5px;">Items to Ship: </span><span style="padding-left:450px;">
        <a href="#" class="MarkAsShipped" data-id="@Model[i].OrderID">Mark as Shipped</a></span><br />
          @for (int x = 0; x < @Model[i].OrderItems.Count(); x++)
          {                   
              @Html.HiddenFor(m => @Model[i].OrderItems[x].OrderProductsID)
              @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => @Model[i].OrderItems[x].isShipped)
              @Model[i].OrderItems[x].ShortDescription
              <br />                  
          }
      </div>
      <div style="clear:left;"></div>
 </div>
 <br />
     }
 }
```

In the controller I return OrderID as Json:

```
return Json(order.OrderID, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: I am helping you in debugging. Remove $(formID).remove() and try. Check if you are getting the viewModel on the 2nd time as well. If yes, then the problem is with remove method.

Comment: After the first ajax call returned successfully, before clicking the remove link 2nd time, go to browser and view source. Check if the HTML tags are proper. There may be a chance that your remove method is corrupting your DOM.

Comment: Thanks Rockstart.  I commented out the "remove" and it is still doing the same.  Do you think it has something to do with "serialize"?

Comment: I also just discovered that the first Order in the list is the only one that works.  So it's not like I can choose any one Order in the list and it will work the first time.  I'm starting to think it must be something in my HTML.  Any other thoughts would be appreciated.  Thanks.